# How to remove blue border between i tags

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
<div class="text-center" style="position: absolute;z-index: 9;bottom: 1%; width:100%; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51);font-size:50px;">
 <i class="fa fa-plus-circle pointer" title="Zoom In" onclick="foyrPlayer.OnPanoramaButtonPressed('zoomin');"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-minus-circle pointer" title="Zoom Out"  onclick="foyrPlayer.OnPanoramaButtonPressed('zoomout');"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left pointer" title="Back"  onclick="prevLevelSection()"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-adjust pointer " title="Change Color"  onclick="toggleVariant();"></i>
</div>
```

when I click on any element more than once, there is a blue color appearing between those, check image

this is not outline. How can I avoid/remove this blue line

[image]

Comment: It's the white-space that is selected on double-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With clicking multiple times in a short amount of time, you activate the text selection. So what you are actually doing is to select the space between the white-elements.

If you want to prevent the selection, you can add an additional class as proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326004/prevent-selection-in-html):

> ```
> *.unselectable {
>    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
>    -khtml-user-select: none;
>    -webkit-user-select: none;
>
>    /*
>      Introduced in IE 10.
>      See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
>    */
>    -ms-user-select: none;
>    user-select: none;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a selection mark of mouse. [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) CSS property can help you to avoid this appearance.