# Remove mobile browser default test selection Action bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a web app using css/html and JS. my major problem is I need to show my own customised action bar when user select the text but in Android and iOS browser show there supported action bar.

In Android old

[image]

above Android M

[image]

iOS

[image]

In above snap you can find default controls of Android and ios. I Just need selection but no need of controls.

and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: this question is just answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Disable text selection in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview)

Comment: Speaking about iOS, you can disable selection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326028/3050403. But you can't disable just "Copy" menu.

Comment: may my way of asking the question is wrong. just i want default test selection with start and end stick. so user can move selection but action should be mine. this thing is possible using css/js or html ?