# Attach noselect to div dynamically without throwing errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
// No select for Internet Explorer
this.gContainer.onmousedown = function(evt) {
    noselect;
}
```

This works great, but throws 'no select unknown' in Chrome/Firefox. I've tried putting try catch block around it, but this stops it functioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using some kind of frameworks? noselect is not a statement. noselect() or something.something='noselect' or you need a function noselect() and then you can use something.someeventhandler=noselect

Comment: No framework, I don't understand why this code works as you say, but it does work for IE!

Comment: Where do you get the noselect from - some tutorial? I think the reason it works in IE is that it stops the script and cancels the onmousedown due to the error. Also please explain WHAT you want to happen. Perhaps we have a better alternative

Comment: It's ok I've fixed it now, it's not valid markup, but worked because IE stops the flow when the error is reached.

Comment: Tim Down's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `noselect` keyword in IE or FF or any browser.

You must have included some script but even then, the syntax you use to call it is wrong.

It gives errors to my IE. What system/app are you developing for ?

Comment: Yeah I can see it's kinda wrong but I've tried a lot of other things and this is the only thing that works.

Comment: Ah it must be throwing an error in IE and stopping the process because if I change it to anything it still works guess I'll go back and figure it out properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4)) {

noselect;
  } else
{

 evt.noselect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFIAK, there is "noselect" keyword on IE and/or FF or any browsers. Even if there is I think using noselect; doesn't take any effect, it should have been an assignment or perhaps a function call like **noselect=true;**  or **noselect();**

if noselect is a function not an attribute this will eliminate the error on any browser:

```
this.gContainer.onmousedown = function(evt) {
    if(window.noselect) //if noselect is on global or <objectcontext>.noselect if not
        noselect();
}
```