# Make all text EXCEPT <input> unselectable in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a website where I want to disable users from selecting content EXCEPT for input areas. I currently have some CSS to disable user-select:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

However, this does NOT cover Internet Explorer; thus, I need to implement some JavaScript:

```
<body onselectstart="return false;">
```

Through CSS and JavaScript, I can make all content unselectable across all popular browsers. BUT, this code also makes  areas unselectable, which is a major case of poor usability. I use CSS to make input areas selectable:

```
-webkit-user-select: text;
-khtml-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
-o-user-select: text; 
user-select: text;
```

.. and as you might have expected, this does not cover Internet Explorer, since I used JavaScript to disable all content from being selectable.

What can I do to make all content unselectable except for input areas?

Comment: No answer, only a question occurs to me - _Why in the world would you do that?_
Not for "security". That's just going to annoy me and then I'll **Ctrl+U** to view source and copy from there instead.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the event is bubbling up to the body and not originating there, I think you can check the node name for the actual target node, and avoid returning false for events occurring on certain nodes:

```
<body onselectstart="if ((event.target || event.srcElement).nodeName !== 'INPUT') return false;">
```

Comment: This is the approach I went with; it was very straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: oncontextmenu="return false;"

Put that in your body tag, then use something like:

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

in a javascript function for the input items you want selectable. That should stop the propagation of the event that would trigger the body tag.

Comment: Of course, this solution is assuming that JavaScript is turned on in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the proprietary IE attribute `unselectable="on"` to any element that you want to make unselectable in IE:

```
<p unselectable="on">I don't want IE users to easily select this text 
  for some reason.</p>
```

See [Making things unselectable in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie) for a more detailed explanation.

If doing this from javascript, be sure to use `el.setAttribute("unselectable","on")`.  Just using `el.unselectable="on"` will not work.

Comment: This is a great idea for particular elements. However, I'd love to apply this to all elements.