# CSS Text Selection override for Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a layout as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="Non-Select">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div><input name="title" type="textbox" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
Non-Select {
  user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

I want to be able to override the Non-Select class so that I can select text in the Text Box.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make text unselectable one needs to understand that there are *two* methods. If we need Opera and Internet Explorer prior to version 10 (which is in most of the cases positive)) ) - we need to use the `unselectable` attribute with the value of `on`.

What is important to notice here that if we set this attribute to the *parent* wrapper - `.Non-Select` in this case - the child-elements' text can still be selected - open [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxnEb/4/) in opera or IE up to 9 to check. So we need to add this attribute to **every single element that should not be selected** (possibly dynamically via javascript if there are many (or unknown number) of possible child elements).

To disable other browsers' selection we may use the css3 [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property. A cool way of adding this css will be via `attribute selector` like so:

```
[unselectable="on"]{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
```

Thus - the text on any element with this attribute cannot be selected in most of the popular browsers.

The second way is shorter. If we don't need IE or Opera - your code must undergo a small change for it to work in Firefox, Chrome and IE10.

```
.Non-Select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
.Non-Select input {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text; 
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text; 
}
```

Pay attention to the non-standart `-moz-none` value I added. If we read carefully about [this property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-user-select) we will see that Mozilla introduced this non-standart version *to enable selection of child elements*. A live example of the second method can be seen here: - http://jsfiddle.net/jxnEb/5/

**Edit:** There has been [a similar question on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie). Pay attention to the accepted answer where the author wrote a function to add the `unselectable` attribute recursively to all the child-elements. (in your case - `input` should be filtered of course).

Comment: @SJacks any details?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that what you wrote is actually partially correct but the solution is a lot more simple than is being presented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520475/css-override-disable-text-selection/59520476#59520476

Comment: @SJacks I seem to struggle to find any difference between this answer and the one from your link. The fact that in 2012 we needed a couple of vendor prefixes doesn't count, It's still `user-select: none`. Why is it partially correct?

Comment: Because of the vendor fixes, they are not semantic and are no longer required.

Comment: @SJacks your comment is (to put it mildly) incorrect. Firstly, CSS properties cannot be semantic or unsemantic, this adjective is not for CSS. Secondly, we _do_ need some vendor prefixes (even though it's 2020), take a [look](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_user-select) at caniuse. The only thing that we can remove from my answer is the `khtml` one.

Comment: You're wrong. Whether you agree or not the fact is CSS is a language and thus it can be written in a semantic or unsemantic manner. Try W3C's CSS validator (Jigsaw) which reveals semantic errors. In this case user-select is the only required value. I have tested this myself on multiple browsers and devices including mobile and desktop.

Comment: @SJacks one last time - there's nothing unsemantic in a vendor prefix. They've been the _recommended_ way to implement features for browsers without awaiting for the official spec. Secondly (about your testing) if you can please open [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zwr0ody/1/) in Edge to confirm that the text is unselectable? It's your fiddle not mine :) lol. This should conclude our conversation on this

Comment: Paste your code here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator the only valid CSS is user-select:text; As for Edge... It's not anywhere near a significant share of the market and if that's your argument, it's a poor one. Have a productive and semantic day!

Comment: @SJacks You're punching above your weight my friend :) a) do you have anything to prove your claim that `W3C's CSS validator (Jigsaw) which reveals semantic errors`? Cause I don't think this is true. Validity and semantics are like chalk and cheese. b) This [thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2005Dec/0012.html) explains why the validator marks vendor prefixes as errors. Please read and provide an answer to me in your next comment at to _why_. Don't worry, the thread is 7 short emails long.

Comment: "You're punching above your weight" LOL okay ;) Safari is worthy of consideration due to the widespread use of Apple products, particularly the iPhone, however, Edge is not. As for IE, it's nearly dead: ask yourself where the limit lies in cross platform support, how old or how underused does the software or hardware have to be in order for you to drop support for it. There have to be limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can override your default behaviour for inputs within Non-Select.

```
.Non-Select{
  user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.Non-Select input{
  user-select: text; 
  -khtml-user-select: text; 
  -moz-user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to check what you suggest?

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I globally disabled text selection and wanted to re-enable it on some specific elements. This should be the accepted answer as it is the only one which works.

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS

```
.Non-Select input {
  user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want to be able to make the text in the text box selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your CSS like this:

```
.Non-Select {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
      -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
           user-select: none; 
}
```

You forgot a dot before class name.

That will be enough to achieve desired result.