# css override disable text selection

Tags: css, text

Some people like to disable text selection for various reasons like keeping it on can make a page look ugly if someone hits CTRL A, or maybe you don't want people potentially leaving your site after highlighting text to search for on Google!

I globally disabled text selection on my site and wanted to re-enable it on specific elements as required. After some investigation, I found the solution.

All the code listed is tested and working on multiple browsers.

**CSS** example of globally disabling text selection.

```
* {user-select:none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution. Please check out the jsfiddle link below for a working example.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Unselectable/Selectable</h2><br/>
<p>You can't select any of this text but you can select the text in the box below because a css rule has been made specifically to reenable text selection for that particular element.<br/><br/></p>
<input name="title" id='selectMe' type="textbox" />
```

**CSS**

```
* {padding:20px; user-select:none;}
#selectMe {user-select:text; border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zwr0ody/1/