# How to get rid of useless selection on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I have a very strange question. Whenever i drag click and drag my mouse from bottom of my page to top. Everything single thing on the screen get selected. Including empty tag spaces.
Is there any solution to select only and only the texts?

[image: Problem image]

Comment: Yes, paste in notepad and you will only get text :)

Comment: You can make elements on a page unselectable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448671/making-things-unselectable-in-ie. Different approaches in different browsers though. I believe this article gives you different ways of doing it

Comment: I dont want extract text from site. I only wish site to look cleaner! And yes currently i am using that(user-select:none;) as a temp. solution.