# prevent text selection when dragging bootstrap-slider handle in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-slider

I'm using bootstrap-slider with two sliders on a single page. My problem is that the text in the page gets selected if I drag the mouse away of the handle while still dragging it.

The problem is also present on the [demo page](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) (Firefox only).

The problem can be seen in the image below:

[image: The problem can be seen in the image below]

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931620/how-to-prevent-text-selection-when-dragging-mouse-in-firefox) but it didn't work.

**Update**: It only happens in Firefox, not Chrome.

Comment: set `user-select: none` on the tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for all browsers:

```
.slider .tooltip-inner {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
    -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this CSS to a class called `no_select` and added `$("body").addClass('no_select');` when sliding.

Comment: I had to apply these styles to the whole `.slider` class (i.e. remove `.tooltip-inner`)