# how to disable image selection using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when we drag over an image, the image become selected. how can i disable this selection using jquery or javascript? I am trying to create a custom image crop script.  i tried `e.preventDefault()` but it is not working in IE6, please help

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make text unselectable on an html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page)

Comment: The duplicate is referring to text, but the solution is 100% identical for images, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are also some css properties like -webkit-user-select: none; and -moz-user-select:none

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use a [existing tool](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/) for that or look at the code to understand what it is you are missing.