# HTML : Make the text unselectable

Tags: html, select, text

there is text but you cannot select it

[check this out](http://www.metrolyrics.com/wont-go-home-without-you-lyrics-maroon-5.html)

- How to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a question, or are you telling us to check out a website?

Comment: Great way to have noone visit the website you're making. I'd sure as hell pick an alternative.

Comment: He's asking how to achieve it, clearly English is not Junaid's first language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make text unselectable on an html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of scripts available on the net, the one proposed by @mellowsoon is one of them.

However remember that it does not make text selection impossible, it just makes it difficult. Text selection can be "re-enabled" by the user by just disabling javascript or from the source by page.

Also such not selectable text is not very usable and may leave users frustrated.

If you are concerned with someone copying *your* content without your permission, use appropriate licenses and copyright, rather than such techniques (or use technologies like flash if applicable, but even here there are OCR techniques that can help copying text)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with jQuery. Check [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) sources, for example:

```
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

There's a [post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disableselection) from jquery forum explaining the situation around `disableSelection`. Looks like it's 'undocumented' for a long time already.