# Disabling list highlight when clicking on the list bullet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have a simple list : example : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

I am using Mozilla Firefox (version 3.6 but I think version does not matter). When I click (single) on the bullet, the list item gets selected(highlighted).

Is there a way to disable this highlighting (without removing the highlighting forever using -moz-selection)?

This behavior is not seen in Chrome or IE.
Another example : (with list-style-image) : http://www.sendesignz.com/Demo/jQuery/expanding_list_item/expanding.html

Is there a way in plain javascript or jQuery or css to disable this auto selection in FF?

Comment: this article may help : http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=848814

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 2):

It's functionality implemented by Firefox as you could tell, while I don't know of any true way to remove the functionality there is a CSS workaround you can do.

Wrap all contents of the `<li>` in a `<span>`, and then using *margin*, *padding* and *absolute positioning* to position the span over the list item.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><span>Item</span></li>
<li><span>Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li span{
    margin-left: -50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mozilla css parameter

**CSS**

```
 li {-moz-user-select: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection seems to be related to the mousedown event. You can block it by stopping the event. For exemple in jQuery :

```
elt.mousedown(function(event){ return false; });
```

Comment: You should consider adding `if (event && event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();` to your function as well.