# Text Highlighting When Dragging From Other Elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, highlighting

I am still stuck on a highlighting problem in IE 7/8. I have tried [applying CSS from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting), changing the `onselectstart` event to return false, adding the attribute `unselectable="on"`, and anything else I could find here on SO.

Then I came across this response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214128/text-unselectable-in-ie):

> Once an element is unselectable, users cannot select from within that
>   element. However, they are still able to select either the text or the
>   box of the element by dragging into it from within another element
>   which is not unselectable.
>
> I have tried to work around this by cancelling various events on
>   myElement (ondragenter, oncontrolselect, onmouseenter,
>   onselectionchange...), it didn't work.

This is exactly what I am trying to do. I have a [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) canvas object that the user can drag in order to draw. However, if they leave the canvas I do not want text in "outside" elements to be highlighted. I was wondering if anybody has found a hack for the quoted problem.  I'm only having this problem in IE 7/8.

Answer (score 0):

use JQUERY

```
$('#dragelement').onMouseDown(function(){
//YOUR CODE
});
```