# HTML/Javascript: Disable Copy and Pasting of Certain DIVS

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find a way to prevent the user from copy and pasting a particular DIV in an html file.  I am limited to HTML and Javascript as this wont be hosted on a real webserver, just a network drive.  I am also stuck dealing with IE8 specifically.

Basically the page has 2 main DIVs.  One visible and One not (long story) but I need a way to make it so that if a user highlights the entire page or CTRL-A's, they dont get the content of the second DIV.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214128/text-unselectable-in-ie

Comment: Keep in mind it still can be copied from page source

Comment: I read that alraedy. If you read the solution in that post it specifically mentions you can still copy text in an unselectable element if you start your highlighting in a selectable element like my first one, or in a CTRL-A situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden iframe with the contents of that second div.

Comment: Trying that at the moment but its causing my grief because I cannot clone elements out of the iframe into the first div