# Prevent 'rapid' clicking of a UI element from selecting text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm developing a Javascript slider that implements back/forward arrows for navigation. My problem is that rapidly clicking the 'Forward' arrow selects text. (Though for some reason this doesn't happen when rapidly clicking any of my other buttons.) I basically have the same problem as the OP in [this][1] question, but none of the answers work for me. I don't have the option of using `<button>`'s, I even tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: By `<button>` do you mean `<input type="button">`?

Comment: there is no demo of the slider

Comment: He means the left/right buttons, not an actual "slider"

Comment: @Tim, no. Check the accepted answer in the other question I link to.

Comment: @EvilP smpl.graphicfaction.com

Comment: @DC yeah I can click links but I'm using Firefox and I can't see left right buttons or any slider elements on your page there are only images

Comment: Have you seen this question on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page

Comment: @EvilP Hmm, I haven't tested in FF yet and don't have access to it right now. Can you try Chrome?

Comment: no I'm not using Chrome.

Comment: Works on Chrome 18/Dev on Mac.

Comment: well, in that the slider works, but it IS highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the arrow images the background for the `<a>` items, try actually placing the `<img>`s inside of the `<a>` tags.  I believe the problem is that the browser thinks you're clicking on the background - which you effectively are - and many clicks on the background highlights text.

You said you don't have the option of using `<button>` -- What other limitations are we working with?

Comment: Won't that just cause the image to become selected on rapid clicking rather than text in the background?

Comment: You could then put the image inside of `<button>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to disable the selection of text which can be done like the accepted answer in this question [How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

or if you're using jQueryUI you can just do

```
$('#mydiv').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that adding this to your css should do the work:

```
a.someClass { 
-webkit-touch-callout: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; 
user-select: none; 
}
```

Comment: This works great and has the added bonus that I can apply this fix on sites that aren't mine (looking at you GoG) by using a plugin to add CSS to the page. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your link for a little time:

```
//Change image
//Disable the link (the arrow)
setTimeout(function()
    {
    //Enable your link
    }, 300); //300 is a time in ms
```

A plugin of JQuery allows you to disable/enable pretty much any field in the page: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryenabledisable