# CSS Button selects entire section on double click

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi I've made two little buttons which are divs with click event attached . Both of them of position:absolute and have the same z-index . The problem is when I double click on just the right button it selects the entire section below it . I've tried attaching a `.dblclick(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });` on the section, body and button , this didn't work .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your html / button

```
unselectable="on" class="unselectable"
```

CSS

```
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

`unselectable="on"` is for IE and Opera.

You might also wanna take a look here: [unselectable Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page) and Tim Downs answer.