# Prevent highlighting canvas area in Chrome

Tags: css, html

On our whiteboard application, Chrome users are able to highlight the entire canvas if they drag their mouse a certain way:

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying this CSS to the body seems to do the trick for me in Chrome:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Others have said that these properties are not yet respected by Opera and IE, and instead, you need to set the unselectable attribute on the elements, like so:

```
<body unselectable="on">
```

I don't have either of those browsers, so I can't confirm this, but you can see these posts for more detail:

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

[Is there a way to make text unselectable on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page)

Comment: I've just added this to an app I'm working on (All current browser revs as per 22nd July 2016) I can confirm that the css in the first chunk of code works in IE11, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Maxathon in a consistent manner.  I have however, just checked the whatwg & css wg specs, and the "user-select" css is still in working draft, and has been since September 2015.  Can I use however, reports it as fully implemented in all browsers except for opera-mini.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS to the CANVAS element,
If you apply this css to body, than your text and etc selection will be disabled, so be careful.

```
  canvas{
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     -o-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
  }
```