# Stop a shift click from highlighting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table on my web page that have checkboxes on them.
I have jquery code that allows me to shift click to check multiple rows for editing/removal.
But when I shift click to select a range all of the text inside the range gets highlighted.

Is there any way using jquery or css to stop the text from being highlighted?

--EDIT--

```
    HTML code
...
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cam_ip">192.168.200.78</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cam_ip">192.168.200.250</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

There can be x amount of rows.
The jquery works when I click a row, that row is marked as an anchor, then when I shift click on another row it is marked as anchorrange, then a function is called which will loop through each row inside the range making it checked.
The side effect of using `e.shiftClick();` is that all the text within the range gets highlighted. I need to stop this side effect.

Comment: You gotta show us your code + which plugin you use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS version

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
```

also a possible related question to [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Year later edit (integrating from comment):

Colleague pointed this out [Is there a way to make text unselectable on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page) - use `unselectable="on"` on whatever you want not selectable

Comment: This code works on all browsers except for IE, I tried changing `user-select: none;` to `ms-user-select: none;` but still no luck. Would you know any reason why this is happening?

Comment: it appears that -ms-user-select is new in IE10 http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/  since this is the case, I'd imagine that its not supported at all for <ie9.  I don't know that there's a pure CSS way of doing this for those browsers, then.

Comment: Colleague pointed this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page   use 'unselectable="on"' on whatever you want not selectable