# jquery - can't select text on complex page - how do I debug this?

Tags: debugging, mouseevent, jquery

I'm not able to select text on a page that has a lot of jquery and css stuff going on. I've commented out many of the mousedown event handlers that seem like obvious culprits, but I still haven't found the bug.

The question is... what's the best way to debug this? Is there a better way to debug this than commenting out all event handlers until I find the problem? Is there some sort of event inspector I can use?

FYI, the page is:

http://www.musiclessons.com/youtube/#6NxVucKQHG8 - you can't select any text below the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there it is:

```
$('#youtube-list').disableSelection ();
```

found in the following file, loaded by your page:

http://musiclessons.com/youtube/js/youtube.js?v=9

and here's what it's about:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disableselection

as for your question on an efficient way of debugging this: i don't really know. was looking through the css files for some 'user-select' property (see [Is there a way to make text unselectable on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430/176140)), then read some of the js, before stumbling upon the above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that might be there for when the user drags things around without text being selected. I totally missed this.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you need to select the text to debug, perhaps you can update the question with that.

For now, if you need to copy the text or something like that, you can always inspect with firebug or whatnot and select the text from there.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding my question... The bug is that a user cannot select any text on the page. So if a user wants to select and then copy any text within the page, they cannot do that. My question has to do with how to debug this because it has to do with event handlers on the page, which there are many. So it's not an easy debugging task. I'm wondering if there are any tricks or tools that might help.

Comment: Did u find any solution ?? I am also looking for the solution.