# DragAndScroll Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello so I would like to make drag and scroll using jquery or javascript.
I was looking on internet for some examples but I couldn't find anything.
Can somebody give me some example of drag and scroll script? (I want use it inside of scroll box)

Kind regards,

Artur

Comment: I found this solution. Just add it on your scroll box.

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19743358/3478580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd like pep.

very simple. I put together a demo inside a scrolling div for you:

here's a drag-and-scroll demo:

## [Drag and Scroll](http://codepen.io/briangonzalez/pen/evwko)

## [Simple Demo](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/raeXjP)

[image: demo]

jquery

```
    $(function() {
        $('.container .pep').pep();
    });
```

html

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="pep"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hallo I have problem I made scrollbox with can be scrolled by mouse.But the problem is that I need to click left button on mouse and then leave div container to move to the bottom.

Comment: not sure what you mean. Check the drad and scroll demo above.