# Make whole page draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure where to start with this or even what keywords to search for, so I am asking for someone to point me in the right direction. Here is what I am wanting.

I am wanting to make a webpage that can be dragged in all directions with different HTML elements in all directions and load new elements as you get close to the edges via AJAX. I am hoping to achieve this via Bootstrap or JQuery.

Any ideas on how to get the page draggable like that?

Comment: @humble.rumble that does not seem to be doing what I want it to do.. It just makes it where you can drag the element in other parts of the page.. I want the page to "scroll" in all directions. http://jsfiddle.net/vf0b7pLL/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI has a draggable method that would work for you, as long as you target the viewable area as the element to initiallize the plugin on. If you prefer a more lightweight approach you can use this plugin created by Chris Coyier.: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/.

An example of it working in just 2 directions would be found in this SO thread as well: [Scroll the page on drag with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743228/scroll-the-page-on-drag-with-jquery) however the actual plugin being used in the demo supports all direction dragging - see the authors site: http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/