# Avoid the li tag symbol from being copied

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm new here so I'll try to explain what I want.
(and also sorry if this is a stupid question)

I made a html webpage containing some information listed (servers name) with  tags (unordered list), and some colleagues are complaining because when they copy the server name and paste it on linux command prompt, the symbol appears behind.

So, my question is: Is there any way to avoid the symbol from being copied when they make a copy/paste of the name?

Best Regards.

Comment: Tell them to change there browser/os. Or copy one line at a time. Style should not be copied that is just annoying or it should be a preference set to false by default.

Comment: @mathk that's really annoying yes, but I have to change it, so next time I won't be annoyed again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try setting a css rule like this:

```
ul li {
    list-style-image: url(http//example.com/bulletpoint.jpg);
}
```

to replace the default text bullet point. That way when copying the text the image wont get copied.

Another option is making the bullet points unselectable see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page), for good information on how to do that. The CSS selector you would use would probably have to be 'ul' (to disable), followed by 'ul li' to re-enable selection of the useful text.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

HTML

```
<ul class="list_1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
<ul>
```

CSS

```
.list_1
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: that's good, but I would prefer that the image stayed there so the info could be "marked" as different from the others.