# Prevent text selection on dbl click

Tags: javascript, html, css, textselection

I need to prevent text selection on double click. But the text should be still selectable on mouse drag. Is it possible?

If I try to remove selection on `dblclick` or `mouseup` it flashes (like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2kpcwb6/)) what is not desirable as well.

UPD: **I don't need to disable selection completely**; I only want to disable it on double click.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/z2kpcwb6/2/

**HTML:-**

```
<h2>Try to select me</h2>

<div id="foo" unselectable="on">dljafdlhjafdbdfasjhadsfh adfsjlfhads h jkfkaj fjf ajksfhajks afjk sdhfkj asfadks jfsdjf kjasdhf kjasdh fkjasdfk jadskjfhakdsjf kajsdf kjah kfjas kdjfads</div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
#foo {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: @odedta Does this answer your query?

Comment: I didn't post the question, in any case, this seems like a viable solution to me. :)

Comment: This is a CSS3 property. Please find the browser support here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: @In case you are targetting old browser use jQuery `.disableSelection()`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to disable selection completely

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is no css solution for this, because there is no way to block **only** the doubleclick selection, but let the text be selectable over drag. You can however completely block the selection with css user-select:none;

However you could check in javascript for the doubleclick event and then remove the selection with 
    window.getSelection().empty();

Comment: Yes, I can remove selection on `doubleclick` (as I mentioned in my post) but it flashes

Answer (score 0):

Use this pseudo-selector when ever you need in your code:

```
::selection {
    background: transparent;
    color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript solution should work in all browsers:

```
<div onselectstart="return false">your text</div>
```

Or you can use a css solution that works in most browsers:

```
.not-selectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;    
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Note: If I remember correctly, the css solution doesn't work in most mobile browsers.